# How to combine BigQuery LAST_VALUE() and ARRAY_AGG()

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is a toy example:

```
select * 
from(
select 1 as row_num,298807 as id1,104 as id2,'2018-07-10' as date
union all
select 2,298807,104,'2018-08-02'
union all
select 3,298807,104,'2018-08-06'
union all
select 4,298807,104,'2018-08-08'
union all
select 5,298807,104,'2018-08-24'
union all
select 6,298807,104,'2018-09-28'
union all
select 7,298807,104,'2018-10-01'
union all
select 8,298807,104,'2018-10-28'
union all
select 9,298807,300,'2018-10-30'
union all
select 10,298807,104,'2018-11-12'
union all
select 11,298807,300,'2018-11-20'
union all
select 12,298807,104,'2018-11-30'
union all
select 13,298807,104,'2018-12-02'
union all
select 14,298807,104,'2018-12-03')
```

For each row, I would like to find the last row of distinct id2 within id1.
For example for row #11 the output should be an array of two elements “row #9, row#10”,
and for row #14 it is “row #11,row #13”.

here is an example output:
[image]

Comment: How many different values do you have for `id2`?

Comment: Anything between 1 and 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(candidates),
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT CAST(MAX(row_num) AS STRING) row_num
    FROM t.candidates
    GROUP BY id2
    ORDER BY row_num
  ), ',') AS output
FROM (
  SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id2, row_num)) OVER(win) candidates
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
) t
-- ORDER BY row_num
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row row_num id1     id2 date        output   
1   1       298807  104 2018-07-10       
2   2       298807  104 2018-08-02  1    
3   3       298807  104 2018-08-06  2    
4   4       298807  104 2018-08-08  3    
5   5       298807  104 2018-08-24  4    
6   6       298807  104 2018-09-28  5    
7   7       298807  104 2018-10-01  6    
8   8       298807  104 2018-10-28  7    
9   9       298807  300 2018-10-30  8    
10  10      298807  104 2018-11-12  8,9  
11  11      298807  300 2018-11-20  10,9     
12  12      298807  104 2018-11-30  10,11    
13  13      298807  104 2018-12-02  11,12    
14  14      298807  104 2018-12-03  11,13
```

Comment: MIkhail, this is an amazing stuff, still need to get down to the intrinsic of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using arrays.  Amass a big array with all the values.  Then use `unnest()` and some aggregation logic to get what you want:

```
with t as (
select * 
from(
select 1 as row_num,298807 as id1,104 as id2,'2018-07-10' as date
union all
select 2,298807,104,'2018-08-02'
union all
select 3,298807,104,'2018-08-06'
union all
select 4,298807,104,'2018-08-08'
union all
select 5,298807,104,'2018-08-24'
union all
select 6,298807,104,'2018-09-28'
union all
select 7,298807,104,'2018-10-01'
union all
select 8,298807,104,'2018-10-28'
union all
select 9,298807,300,'2018-10-30'
union all
select 10,298807,104,'2018-11-12'
union all
select 11,298807,300,'2018-11-20'
union all
select 12,298807,104,'2018-11-30'
union all
select 13,298807,104,'2018-12-02'
union all
select 14,298807,104,'2018-12-03') 
)
select tt.* except (ar),
       (select array_agg(row_num order by el.row_num)
        from (select el.id2, max(el.row_num) as row_num
              from unnest(ar) el
              where el.row_num <= tt.row_num
              group by el.id2
             ) el
       ) as id2s
from (select t.*,
             array_agg(struct(row_num, id2)) over (partition by id1) as ar
      from t
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Nice, this is the approach i was eventually taking.

Comment: @ronencozen . . . Just so you know my opinion, I think this is a better solution than converting the values to a string.  An array-only solution preserves the original data and is more generalizable for different data types, including structures.

Comment: Hi Gordon, agree about the generalization, the advantage of the string approach has to do with the cost of the query. in BigQuery you pay for number of rows processed and the string approach produce much less rows compare to array-only, hence it is more economical.

Comment: number of rows = Bytes processed.

Comment: @ronencozen . . . The same data is processed.  It should be the same cost.  BigQuery charges on the amount of data *read*.